# Flip global boolean value by reference

Tags: powershell, reference, global-variables

I'm just wondering how I can flip global variable by reference. There are no issues without reference or with local variables. But when I'm using global variable then I always getting same output

Like:

```
$global:online = $true

function Get
{
  [REF]$global:online.Value = !([REF]$global:online.Value)
  return [REF]$global:online.Value
}

Get
Get
```

And the output will be:

```
Value
-----
False
False
```

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: @thepip3r it was called twice, so the output should be False and then True in theory

Comment: My question is: why would you need to modify a global variable by reference?

Comment: @thepip3r my expectation is to receive false then true but I'm getting only false

Comment: @briantist just practice. nothing more. Just want to understand why it doesn't work

Comment: `[ref]$global:online.Value` -> `([ref]$global:online).Value`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen are you the new PetSerAl ;-p

Comment: @briantist damn, I guess I am ^_^